# Help with shells

Tags: discussion, macos

Newbie here. I (still) use the MacOS terminal a lot. I have some very specific questions about bash.

Can someone tell me where the best place to post these might be?

Answer (score 3):

Shell questions are on-topic on AskDifferent and on Unix&Linux. Whichever site you choose, please check existing questions about the same topic first and do not post a specific question on both sites.

Comment: Possibly also on topic on Stack Overflow and also check answers on Ask Ubuntu ie use google/bing search first